# what's the point in html paragraph tags with long randomized ids?

Tags: jquery, html

I saw a webpage with tags like this (p id="zw-13733b2dc46p4lOvv123628e") and (p id="zw-13733b5602cFOXxgp123628e"). So apparently ids are similar but not equal and randomized. What's the point? If they are manipulating these paragraphs with jquery, why don't they use class tag instead of weird ids? Is there some esoteric reason here or is it just a weird and possibly dumb design?

Comment: Wait... wait... dang it... my crystal ball is a little cloudy. Let me go get my tarot cards...

Comment: Question lacks specificity.  But it's almost certainly auto-generated by a framework.  I've seen instances in which some DOM behavior becomes more predictable when an ID is present, and for interaction of some specific widgets, ID is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not dumb design**, usually they are used by application/framework to identify certain parts so they can be manipulated easily. Users does not need to know what they mean and site developers indirectly knows what they mean.

ID is generated randomly and often some seed like `microtime` is used to get unique ID. Framework can for example provide methods to add new paragraph that can be identified and therefore dynamically changed, removed, moved and so on.

What is important when using random ID's is that application developer can somehow keep track of them, for example, in web server's source code it can be like this (*there's jQuery tag in your question but... not enough information to answer specifically so here's some pseudocode*):

```
$link_to_home$ = new object tagWithRandomID("Homepage");
insertTagToPage( $link_to_home$ );
```

And user, when examining source delivered to browser, sees this:

```
...
<a href="http://example.com/?aiwhiafw=s74Gtr54745uhftg7544n">Home</a>
...
```

**In some situations, only framework developers need to know** what is going on. Example for this behavior is when some common containers is automatically inserted to page, like wrappers for every `<p>` tag so that tags can be tracked, styled, modified, ... automatically depending on user behavior, requests, time of day, ... anything.

**It's just like files on your harddisk**, each file is identified by some hash or id and that identification is then linked to data and file attributes so that your file explorer could show filenames, creation time, size, ...

You should read some articleas about hashing to understant unique random id's (*or id's that look like random even if they really are not random*). Or maybe look at some design that uses random looking ID's such as http://tinyurl.com or http://goo.gl

Comment: @Marc Yes, there is space for url's, did you really read even last paragraph? URL shortener is good example of random/generated id usage. URL shorteners uses ID's generated by their framework and then full URL's can bee looked up from database whenever request is made. And for other uses it is basically same, only context changes.

Comment: My bad.  Sorry, it was late.  I missed the context.  Deleting original comment...

Answer (score 0):

Usually the id's have been added into the page by a framework such as jQuery - they look random, but have a meaning to the framework - often it's a quick way of indexing the DOM elements.

Post a link to the page and I can have a look for you.